# Problems Building a WCF CRUD operations project

Tags: c#, wcf, methods, client, northwind

**CONRTACT:**

Here is my contract interface, with Crud Operation contracts.

```
[ServiceContract]
public interface IWcfCrudServices
{
    [OperationContract]
    Object addEmployee(Employees employee);
    [OperationContract]
    object getAllEmployees();
    [OperationContract]
    Object updateEmployee(Employees employee);
    [OperationContract]
    object deleteEmployee(Employees employee);
}
```

**LOGIC**
Class with logic crud methods, maybe I am doing something wrong here? Model is working just fine.

```
public class WcfCrudService : IWcfCrudServices
{
    NORTHWNDContext ctx = new NORTHWNDContext();
    public Object  addEmployee(Employees employee)
    {
        ctx.Employees.Add(employee);
        ctx.SaveChanges();
        return ctx.Employees;
    }

    public object deleteEmployee(Employees employee)
    {
        Employees employeeForDelete = ctx.Employees.Find(employee.EmployeeId);
        if (employeeForDelete != null)
        {

            ctx.Employees.Remove(employeeForDelete);
            ctx.SaveChanges();

        }
        return ctx.Employees;

    }

    public object getAllEmployees()
    {
        return ctx.Employees;
    }

    public object updateEmployee(Employees employee)
    {
        Employees employeeForUpdate = ctx.Employees.Find(employee.EmployeeId);
        if ( employeeForUpdate !=null)
        {
            
            employeeForUpdate.FirstName = employee.FirstName;
            employeeForUpdate.LastName = employee.LastName;
            employeeForUpdate.Country = employee.Country;
            employeeForUpdate.City = employee.City;
            employeeForUpdate.Address = employee.Address;

        }
        return ctx.Employees;
        
    }
}
```

}

**HOST**
Host is working just fine, I don't have problem here for sure.

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Uri baseHttpUrl = new Uri("http://localhost:8090/MyServices");
        using (ServiceHost serviceHost = new ServiceHost(typeof(MyServices.WcfCrudService),baseHttpUrl))
        {
            serviceHost.AddServiceEndpoint(typeof(MyServices.IWcfCrudServices), new BasicHttpBinding(), "CrudAssig");
            serviceHost.Open();
            Console.WriteLine("The service is ready.");
            Console.WriteLine("Service name: "+serviceHost.Description.Name);
            Console.WriteLine("Press <ENTER> to terminate the service!");
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

**CLIENT**
My methods not working what ever I do.

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Uri endpointAdress = new Uri("http://localhost:8090/MyServices/CrudAssig");
        EndpointAddress endpoint = new EndpointAddress(endpointAdress);
        IWcfCrudServices proxy = ChannelFactory<IWcfCrudServices>.CreateChannel(new BasicHttpBinding(), endpoint);     
    }
}
```

What to do next? Am I get things wrong in a logic or in a Client ? I am trying to call methods for CRUD operations from the service, and it just not working.

---

Comment: Hello, please have a look at [ask]. Your question, unfortunately, is likely to be closed as it lacks details about what you are trying to do and what problem you are having.

Answer (score 0):

You can call the wcf service in service reference way to detect whether the server has an error. You can publish metadata for your server first, then add a service reference, and call the server through the service reference.

You can view this demo to add metadata to your service:

```
<configuration> 

  <system.serviceModel> 

    <services> 

      <service name="Metadata.Example.SimpleService"> 

        <endpoint address="" 

                  binding="basicHttpBinding" 

                  contract="Metadata.Example.ISimpleService" /> 

      </service> 

    </services> 

    <behaviors> 

  

    </behaviors>  

  </system.serviceModel> 

</configuration>
```

You can also refer to this link:

[How to: Publish Metadata for a Service Using a Configuration File](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wcf/feature-details/how-to-publish-metadata-for-a-service-using-a-configuration-file)

Invoking the service through service reference can check whether there is an error on the server side. If there is no problem with the service call, then the logic of the code may be wrong.